# Encryption of data with multiple possible decryption keys

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design, keys, decryption, key-generation

I'm new to the Cryptography Stack Exchange, so my question might be very naive.

What encryption algorithms are out there that will allow different decryption keys to decrypt the same piece of encrypted data?

For example : If the data that I'm encrypting is just a simple string : `"Test"`

Then applying the encryption algorithm changes it to this : `"532EAABD9574880DBF76B9B8CC00832C20A6EC113D682299550D7A6E0F345E25"`

But then in my algorithm setup; I've made it so the decryption process can use any arbitrary number of keys to get back to my string : `"Test"`

It would also be good that if a person has 1 specific decryption key; then that person shouldn't be able to figure out what the other decryption keys are that would also work, if there are any.

Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a specific security goal in mind?  Or, are you asking out of curiosity?

Comment: @poncho I have data mapped onto nodes in a graph, but there are places where multiple nodes connect to a single one, so my idea was if all the data was encrypted in some sort of sequence; at those places where multiple nodes connect to a single one; I would need multiple decryption keys. But yes it's more of a curiosity, nothing too serious.

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/68069/23115 ?

Comment: There is also the topic of deniable encryption, which is related. Some questions on that topic are also here.